# Unable to destroy session in main domain from subdomain

Tags: php, session, yii, subdomain, logout

My domain name `domain.com` and sub-domain is `user.domain.com`

If I logged in from `domain.com` then its working fine. I am getting all the session data in my `user.domain.com`. While I am logout from `user.domain.com` my main domain `domain.com` still logged in. If I refreshed main domain. Again session set in my `user.domain.com`.

I want to destroy session from all the parent and child domain when click logout from my `user.domain.com` sub-domain.

Yesterday, I have posted forum in here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/76155-logout-issue-in-subdomain

*NB: I would like to know this in core php not Yii framework. If anyone also know in Yii you can post answer here.*

Comment: Only `domain.com` can remove `subdomain.domain.com` session, well unless you do some nifty redirects.

Comment: Did you read, http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7861-sessions-and-subdomains/ same problem.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, I did that. Login working fine also logout parent to child is fine. problem in logout child to parent domain.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I used this code `'components' => array(
   'session' => array(
      'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
      'cookieParams' => array('domain' => '.my-project.loc'),
   ),
),`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to destroy session from both domain.
`domain.com` and `user.domain.com` are two different entities.

If that doesn't work, try [unsetting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the keys before destroying the session.

For example: `unset($_SESSION['id'])`, The `id` will be removed from the `$_SESSION`.